# How do I get cross-site XMLHttpRequest invocations to send credentials using Sails?

Tags: authentication, heroku, sails.js

I am trying to get a cross-origin front-end to behave correctly with a [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org/) back-end hosted at another domain. Specifically, the user authentication and credentials are what is broken.

Everything behaves correctly with the normal `POST, GET,` etc type of database behavior. For example, registration of new users already works.

However, after the user is logged in, the authentication step fails and I receive a `401 Unauthorized`.

Here is what the console is telling me:

```
[Object, "post", "login", "https://small-change-api.herokuapp.com/user/login"] 
 User logged in:  Object {firstName: "John", lastName: "Does", email: "test@work.com", activated: true, superUser: false…}
```

**-- GOOD :)**

```
 [Array[0], "get", "authenticated", "https://small-change-api.herokuapp.com/user/authenticated"]
 GET https://small-change-api.herokuapp.com/user/authenticated 401 (Unauthorized)
```

**-- Not good**

Now, all of this works 100% locally, but hosted on Heroku, something is going wrong :/

Here is some relevant server-side configuration:
*This is in the file `config/cors.js`*

```
module.exports.cors = {

  allRoutes: true,
  origin: 'https://thefrontendorigin.com',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH',
  headers: 'content-type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

};
```

In the front-end `withCredentials` set to true:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({ withCredentials: true });
```

What else do I need to get right? It seems like it should work... :/

Let me know if I need to include any more information!

Thanks.

P.S. Both GH repos are public right now, so let me share those.

[Front-end Github](https://github.com/djlovegrind/gunsDash)

[Back-end Github](https://github.com/djlovegrind/smallChangeAPI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed to do, was go into the CORS settings (Cross-Origin Requests) and add this line:

`headers: 'content-type,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'`

That is the crucial bit I was missing, hope that helps somebody else.